# changing reference value restricted cubic spline inside a function in r

Tags: r

I cannot force the rc splines prediction reference to change when it is inside a function. I want the age 65 to be the reference (yhat=1, lower=1, upper=1). It works perfectly when the code is outside the function "analysis". I suspect that the "update" doesn't take place when it is inside the function, even though the dd$limits does change to reference 65 (see output). Probably different environment? I tried for hours to set environment etc, unfortunately without success. Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
    library(Hmisc)
    library(survival)
    library(rms)
    library(cmprsk)

    bk.tst <- function(analysis) 
    {
    if (analysis=="test") {
        dt<-m
    }
    outcomes<-c("compos", "acs", "death", "vascdeath", "stroke", "majbleed")
    for (i in outcomes) {
     fvl<- dt$fvl
     age<-dt$age
     ndt <- data.frame(age, fvl)
     dd<-assign('dd', datadist(ndt), pos=1) 
     options(datadist='dd')
     tm<-paste("tt",i, sep="")
     SurvObj <- with(dt, Surv(eval(parse(text=tm)), eval(parse(text=i))==1))
     f<-cph(SurvObj ~ fvl*rcs(age,c(60,70,80)), type="Survival", method="exact", x=T, y=T)
     print(dd$limits) 
     dd$limits["Adjust to","age"] <- 65
     print(dd$limits)
     g <- update(f)
     ano<-anova(f)
     age.intr.rcsplines<-Predict(g, age=45:85, fvl, ref.zero=TRUE, fun=exp) 
     print(age.intr.rcsplines[20:22,])
     }
    }

    bk.tst("test")

#the output is:
                     age fvl
Low:effect      57.01027   0
Adjust to       64.62697   0
High:effect     71.69884   1
Low:prediction  39.48545   0
High:prediction 84.64122   1
Low             35.80287   0
High            92.15606   1
                     age fvl
Low:effect      57.01027   0
Adjust to       65.00000   0
High:effect     71.69884   1
Low:prediction  39.48545   0
High:prediction 84.64122   1
Low             35.80287   0
High            92.15606   1
   age fvl     yhat     lower    upper
20  64   0 0.986740 0.9599284 1.014300
21  65   0 1.008632 0.9929697 1.024541
22  66   0 1.034987 0.9799775 1.093084

# when the code is outside the function analysis, then the output is correct with 65 as a reference. That is what I want to happen also inside the function "analysis":
                     age fvl
Low:effect      57.01027   0
Adjust to       64.62697   0
High:effect     71.69884   1
Low:prediction  39.48545   0
High:prediction 84.64122   1
Low             35.80287   0
High            92.15606   1
                     age fvl
Low:effect      57.01027   0
Adjust to       65.00000   0
High:effect     71.69884   1
Low:prediction  39.48545   0
High:prediction 84.64122   1
Low             35.80287   0
High            92.15606   1
   age fvl      yhat     lower    upper
20  64   0 0.9782956 0.9369436 1.021473
21  65   0 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000
22  66   0 1.0261294 0.9868852 1.066934
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, defining the environment in the function bk.tst as shown below worked!

```
bk.tst <- function(analysis, env = parent.frame()) 
{
if (analysis=="test") {
    dt<-m
}
outcomes<-c("compos", "acs", "death", "vascdeath", "stroke", "majbleed")
for (i in outcomes) {
 fvl<- dt$fvl
 age<-dt$age
 env$ndt <- data.frame(age, fvl)
 env$dd<-datadist(env$ndt) 
 options(datadist='dd')
 tm<-paste("tt",i, sep="")
 SurvObj <- with(dt, Surv(eval(parse(text=tm)), eval(parse(text=i))==1))
 env$f<-cph(SurvObj ~ fvl*rcs(age,c(60,70,80)), type="Survival", method="exact", x=T, y=T)
 print(env$dd$limits) 
 env$dd$limits["Adjust to","age"] <- 65
 print(env$dd$limits)
 g <- update(env$f)
 ano<-anova(g)
 age.intr.rcsplines<-Predict(g, age=45:85, fvl, ref.zero=TRUE, fun=exp) 
 print(age.intr.rcsplines[20:22,])
 }
}

bk.tst("test")
```